# Send Adaptive Card in an email with c#

Tags: c#, smtp, adaptive-cards

I would like to send an adaptive card in an email (using smtp), from a c# dll. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268814/how-to-send-a-simple-adaptive-card-via-email) post, which only does html. I need to be able to include all the standard adaptive elements, especially actions. I can only seem to find javascript or python examples of how to do this. Can anyone point me at an example of this please!

Comment: Are you writing a bot or something else?

Comment: I'm not writing a bot, I have an application that send emails, and i would like to include adaptive cards in the emails

Comment: Are you using Outlook? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/

Comment: I'm using an app to generate the email, I do not know if the recipient is using Outlook or not